# C# Webmail.Send method how to change person name

Tags: c#, .net, email, webmail

```
 WebMail.SmtpServer = SmtpServer;
                WebMail.UserName = SmtpUsername;
                WebMail.Password = SmtpPassword;
                WebMail.Send(
                        ReplayEmail,
                        subject,
                        body,
                        email
                    );
```

subject is for example "Ask specialist"

body is html body

email is for example "domain@domain.com"

email is send to for example "domain2@domain.com"

now when i send mail i get mail which is ok but as person who send mail I see "domain2@domain.com". how to change this?

mail now looks like

```
domain2@domain.com Ask specialist
```

i want name (Adoo for example) and mail like

`Adoo Ask specialist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when setting up mail you can do :

```
mail.To = new MailAddress("domain2@domain.com", "Adoo");
```

or :

```
mail.To= @"\Adoo \ <domain2@domain.com>";
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `ReplayAddress` is a `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress` defined in code somewhere else you haven't shown. MailAddress has a constructor which takes a string `displayName` which should do what you want if I understand you correctly - documentation on that is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Typically in SMTP you can create a friendly name by using a format like this:

```
   WebMail.Send(
                    "\"Adoo\" <domain2@domain.com>",
                    subject,
                    body,
                    email
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can use

```
mail.To= @"&quot;Adoo&quot; &lt;domain2@domain.com&gt";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the WebMail class which takes a string for the .From property of the class.  I would use the MailAddress class and do:

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("domain2@domain.com", "Adoo Ask specialist");
```